# gnuplot - adding label for the median to the right-hand side of the diagram

Tags: plot, statistics, label, gnuplot, median

I'm using gnuplot's `STATS` to plot a median to some data.

On the right-hand side of the graph, where the median intersects the diagram's border, I should like to place a label stating the median's value - or its percentage of a pre-determined maximum.

How do I best achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a label.  The syntax is

```
set label id "text" at x-coordinate,y-coordinate
```

where the id is optional (but useful if you need to change the label or remove it later).  See `help label` for all of the options (including alignment and font options).

Note also that gnuplot has several coordinate systems.  See `help coordinates` for information about these.

To place a label with the median on the right side at y-coordinate 10 (for example), you can use a command like:

```
set label 1 sprintf("%f",STATS_median) at graph 1, first 10
```

where we use sprintf to turn our numerical value into a string for the label.  We specify the graph coordinate system for the x-coordinate.  This system runs from 0 (left) to 1 (right) and similarly for the y-values from top to bottom.  It is useful for when we need to address relative positions without knowing exact coordinates.  We specify the first coordinate system for the y-coordinate.  This system corresponds to the system used the by x1 and y1 axes.

Note that when placing a label outside the graph (which we have done here), it is sometimes necessary to increase margins.  See `help margins` for full details.  A command like `set rmargin 15` will give enough space for a 15 character string on the right.

For an example, suppose that we have data that looks like

```
8
9
15
3
6
```

Then we can plot this, drawing a line at the median and labeling it with

```
stats datafile nooutput
set arrow 1 from graph 0, first STATS_median to graph 1, first STATS_median nohead
set label 1 sprintf("%0.2f",STATS_median) at graph 1, first STATS_median offset char 1,0
set rmargin 5
plot datafile w points pt 7
```

This produces the following

[image]

Note that we specified an offset on the label in the character coordinate system, which allows us to move it one character width to the right.

---

In this example, an alternative could have been achieved by using the y2 axis and specifying the tic marks literally with

```
set link y
set y2tics ("%0.2f" STATS_median)
plot datafile w points pt 7
```

The advantage here is that the margin is automatically computed.  This is not possible, however, when you need the label elsewhere.